# What's wrong with "the Poincaré" in "the Poincaré conjecture"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I came across [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104514/48776) on Academia.SE and I noticed its first comment. The question points to an article in [the New Yorker magazine](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/08/28/manifold-destiny) written by Sylvia Nasar and David Gruber, both of whom seem to be native English speakers. The comment says:

> I really dislike how the authors of that article keep writing "the Poincaré" for "the Poincaré conjecture".

The comment has gained some upvotes, but I really don't get it. What exactly is wrong with that phrase? Is it the inappropriate use of *"the"*? I am not a native English speaker, but from what I have read/heard so far, I think we *should* use "the" in such cases and it wouldn't sound so annoying.

I hope this question is on topic for this site, because I thought it was about English language ***usage***, and I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: so your beef is: abbreviating 'the Poincare conjecture' to the Poincare or even just Poincare?

Comment: and that in doing so it demeans the man, the field of study?

Comment: Was the downvote really necessary?

Comment: not mine ... my fellow learner!

Comment: The title and body do not match.  The title asks whether a certain subset within the phrase "the Poincaré conjecture" is correct, while the title asks whether *substituting* the subset in place of the entire phrase is correct.  Is this a typo or a symptom of your confusion?

Comment: It's a symptom of my confusion apparently @jwodder

Comment: 'Hamiltonian' is usually used without a head-noun. But 'Maxwell' isn't. It's the way cookies crumble.

Comment: Think how strange it would be if you took a friend to see Formula-1 car racing and they made the comment "wow, look at that fast". Or, if your girlfriend asked what you thought of her new hairstyle and you answered, "that's very".  Don't do that last one, by the way, you'll regret it :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I can't even.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, calling something "very" was a thing for a while - as a compliment. It's immortalized in the movie *Heathers* when Veronica responds to another character's description of something with "How very", and also an ad for a haircare product that had the tag line, "Keri is so very".

Comment: I don't understand why you chose to reject my edit to make the title line up with the body of your question. Yes, it was discussed in the comments, but the comments should be a starting point to improve a question, not a reason not to. You never once explained why you think your title *does* ask the same question as the body. Yes, your confusion may have lead you to write a title that does not reflect the question, but that's not a reason not to improve the title.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the surname of a mathematician as a [metonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) for his famous conjecture seems as counterintuitive as saying Christian fundamentalists don't believe in the Darwin or that some new discovery in astronomical physics substantiates the Einstein.

No one seems to object, however, if someone admires “[the Dior](http://www.redcarpet-fashionawards.com/2015/02/08/felicity-jones-christian-dior-couture-2014-baftas/) she wore to the Golden Globes” or wonders how many [Rembrandts](https://books.google.de/books?id=6DPEfoPxe6IC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=%22how%20many%20rembrandts%22%20museum&source=bl&ots=HDX9yYt989&sig=AuHv5Hwp-9UfdGoM8JFgnd28aww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDttzSvYnaAhUKlSwKHdJEAcsQ6AEwBnoECAIQAQ) might have been destroyed in World War II. A proper name as a metonym for something created by that person, then, is not in itself unusual, but seems so in this context.

In mathematics jargon — which I assume these authors are employing to imply their membership in this discourse community — the name Poincaré, with or without the *accent aigu*, is being used by some writers as a technical term for Poincaré’s conjecture and associated terms such as *map, plot,* or *surface*, as Peter Shor has so kindly pointed out. Once the writer establishes which particular one is meant, as the *New Yorker* article does with *conjecture* several times, then it becomes *the Poincaré* just like the Dior at the Golden Globes.

A simple Google search for [“the Poincaré is”](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22the+Poincar%C3%A9+is%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&hl=de&prmd=minv&ei=3p-3WviJA6Gv6ASd3ZfQDw&start=10&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=748) yielded so many hits  for a variety of omitted nouns I didn’t bother to count them or search using another verb. Such a search cannot, of course, determine how many mathematicians use such a construction as opposed to those who don't or who object to it. All we can know from the posted question is two writers for the *New Yorker* and some dude grousing about it on the internet.

Ultimately, this is a prescriptive-descriptive conflict to be decided by the discourse community that uses the construction.

A few samples show both the variety of contexts and the almost pronomial use of *Poincaré*:

> The [*Poincare*](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/6201373.stm) is a central question in topology, the study of the geometrical properties of objects that do not change when they are stretched, distorted or shrunk. *[Poincaré conjecture]* —BBC news report.

> Although the [*Poincaré*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dddb/0af509fc75b5dbdc6e04dd4321d85401911b.pdf) is useful visual pattern for HRV, it has limitations. *[Poincaré plot]* — International Journal of Medical, Health, Biomedical, Bioengineering and Pharmaceutical Engineering Vol:9, No:9, 2015.

> If the [*Poincaré*](https://books.google.de/books?id=uOAsDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22the+Poincar%C3%A9+is%22&source=bl&ots=F9upuZrmgd&sig=zPvV27nYF89g_PlDmbI3zc_maGg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj48IeZxofaAhWhF5oKHZ3uBfoQ6AEwA3oECAYQAQ) is a finite set of points, then the corresponding system motion is periodic motion state. *[Poincaré map]* — Kehui Sun, *Chaotic Secure Communication*, DeGruyter 2015.

> The [*Poincare*](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-a-poincare-group.520726/) is just what he said: the group of symmetries of flat spacetime. *[Poincaré group]* —Physics Forum post to question “What is a Poincaré group?”

> In the proof of (ii) we use the *Poincaré map* and degree theory. The following lemma guarantees that the *[Poincaré](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X84712625/1-s2.0-S0022247X84712625-main.pdf?_tid=ed5383a3-884e-46a2-8454-2db8a74a93b7&acdnat=1522146227_f6483c7255ae67629de08a0b2998a575)* is well defined. *[Poincaré map]* — Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 185(1994), 480.

> But the implication generally does not go the other way, and since the [*Poincaré*](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/why-is-290-special/) is true there was no special number. *[Poincaré conjecture]* — "Gödel’s Lost Letter and P=NP,” Blog by Prof. Dick Lipton (Georgia Tech) and Prof. Ken Regan (SUNY Buffalo).

> In this paper we discuss the natural candidate for the one dimensional free *Poincaré inequality*... As in the classical case the *[Poincaré](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2013-365-09/S0002-9947-2013-05830-8/home.html)* is implied by the others. — Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 365 (2013), 4811-4849.

From peer-reviewed journals and monographs to blogs and forum posts, some writers, having specified unambiguously which *Poincaré x* is under discussion, then employ *the Poincaré* for subsequent mentions. While this metonymic usage may be the mathematician’s version of the split infinitive or sentence adverb, the variety of genre and the status of the authors within the discourse group — seriously, are you going to tell a tenured professor at Georgia Tech how to write? — suggest that, regardless of one's personal opinion, the usage will not likely disappear any time soon.

Comment: A minor nitpick: in mathematics and dynamical systems, we also have [the Poincaré surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) or Poincaré map, which is sometimes simply referred to as _the Poincaré_.

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ: Yes, I gathered that, but I understand so little of this I hesitated to comment upon it. That usage, however, makes the metonym all the more remarkable. You're welcome to edit this post, since I think some of the citations refer to surface/map.

Comment: In fact, only your first and sixth citation refer to the Poincaré conjecture. Others refer to the ***Poincaré*** map, the ***Poincaré*** plot, the ***Poincaré*** group.  And looking in Google, "the Poincaré" can also mean the Poincaré ***inequality***, the Poincaré ***algebra***, and probably also the Poincaré ***equation***.

Comment: @PeterShor: As I told the other guy whose name I can't type on an iPad, this is even more remarkable if there are six distinct but related terms and you're welcome to edit my post. Are there other mathematicians whose surnames are treated in this fashion or is it only because this guy's name sounds so cool in French?

Comment: @KarlG: first, I think it is probably relatively uncommon for a mathematician to say *"the Poincaré"* rather than *"the Poincaré conjecture"* (although it's clear that sometimes they do). Second, with only a little searching, I found *"the Euler"* used for *"the Euler path"*, *"the Euler constant"*, *"the Euler angle"*, and *"the Euler scheme"*. All of these documents seem to use the full term the first time they use it, and only use *"the Poincaré"* or *"the Euler"* afterwards.

Comment: Jargon is notorious for shorthand expressions opaque to other mortals. On the other hand, the magazine article uses _Poincaré conjecture_  so often in the first part of the article that there's no chance of ambuguity.

Comment: One more nitpick: the Poincaré group, the Poincaré inequality, etc., have nothing to do with the Poincaré conjecture (other than both having been introduced by Henri Poincaré).

Comment: @Karl The fact there are so many possible Poincarés is presumably part of the reason why the commenters on the Academia question took umbrage at the elision.

Comment: But 'Hamiltonians' drop the head-noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think the "Hamiltonian" and  "Poincaré" situations are analogous. "Poincaré" is the man's name; "Hamiltonian" is an adjective derived from the name "Hamilton".

Comment: @AndreasBlas Both are premodifiers licensing the dropping of the head-noun. Other premodifiers of both kinds usually don't allow this.

Comment: This answer is a good *example* of confusion caused by the sloppy language. It's not, in my opinion, a good *answer*.

Comment: @anatolyg: well, you're welcome to venture an answer of your own and pepper it with as much senseless italics as you wish. If you find it confusing, make a suggestion. I’ve incorporated a number of them in the answer.

Comment: The question asks "What's wrong with X?". This answer says "Nothing is wrong with X, as the examples show". While I think that the correct answer is "X can lead to confusion, as the examples show". The other answers are good, but they lack examples.

Comment: quoting @PeterShor *All of these documents seem to use the full term the first time they use it* <- This, I think, is the central point. They've already defined the term in the document, so it's disambiguated. They're clearly *not* talking about some other discovery or concept.

Comment: @anatolyg: The examples attest to the usage after establishing which Poincaré this or that is being discussed, but in most cases I couldn't supply the referrent because Google books would only give me snippet view. They are, however, adequate to the task of demonstrating the metonymic use of the surname, like Dior or Rembrandt. In the _New Yorker_ article it is unambiguous that the Poincaré _conjecture_ is meant. The internet post isn't complaining about possible confusion, but using the name alone.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that "commonly" (in "we have pointed out that _Poincaré_ is commonly used as a metonym for his conjecture") has not been established, neither by the examples nor by any other means. I think academia.se got it right in upvoting that comment. It sounds odd.

Comment: But why "the Poincaré conjecture" rather than "Poincaré's conjecture"?

Comment: @anemone: Someone offered to edit this post to give an actual number of hits, but the suggested edit was rejected before I could get to it. There were nearly 4000. "Common" doesn't suggest "majority" or "approved." I found the usage odd as well, so I was surprised at this vast number of hits. I am not going to come down on one side of a prescriptivist dispute one way or the other simply because I find it odd. If mathematicians want to use this construction, then let them fight it out among themselves. Rembrandt and Dior show it's not that bizarre.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Because such things are inconsistent.  Every mathematician early learns the Pythagorean Theorem, the Peano Axioms/Postulates.  Niels Henrik Abel has many things named after him.  Some are "Abelian", "Abel's", or just "Abel" (although the last is often hyphenated with the name of another mathematician, such as "Abel–Jacobi Theorem").  And mathematics doesn't even suffer from medicine's recent fad of "Dr. ___ didn't actually _have_ the disease he discovered, so we shouldn't call it '___'s Disease/Syndrome' (etc.); we should drop the apostrophe-s."

Comment: @KarlG The number of hits proves little, given that we know neither the nature of the documents nor the intended meaning of the collocation. And, given the total number of mentions of Poincare conjecture, 4k is really negligible anyway. It is easy to handwave any debate about the oddity one phrase or another as a "prescriptivist dispute"; in fact there is none. The commenter at academia.se really disliked it, so did many others. Where's the prescriptivism in that?

Comment: This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Poincare+is%2Cthe+Poincare+*+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthe%20Poincare%20%2A%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20Poincare%20group%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Poincare%20map%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Poincare%20section%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Poincare%20sphere%20is%3B%2Cc0) shows that the metonym *the Poincaré* for *the Poincaré anything* is definitely an infrequent usage.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, that's why I was surprised by the number and quality of the regular Google hits. All I know is that an NGram won't report anything under 40, but there are clearly more instances than that.

Comment: With or without *kink*?

Comment: @anemone: for someone denying the existence of a prescriptivist argument, you certainly relish engaging in one. I am not the least invested in describing 4K hits as "common" usage, so I'll be happy to change it.

Comment: @AzorAhai: it was a joke on _kink field_. Look it up, even if you have to go to urbandictionary.com.

Comment: @KarlG Maybe when I get home from work ...

Comment: The semantic difference between the examples of Dior/Rembrandt vs. Darwin/Einstein/Poincaré may have to do with the former being physical objects and the latter being ideas.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You may be onto something here.  Even GEdgar's example of "The Guggenheim (Museum)", or other buildings are tangible _things_.  Mathematical ideas, scientific discoveries, etc. are very rarely reduced to just the [given or sur-]name of the inventor/discoverer.  The only counter-examples I can think of are figure-skating's Axel [Paulsen], [Ulrich] Salchow, and [Alois] Lutz, but those are often prefaced with "Double", "Triple", or "Quadruple".

Comment: @MontyHarder: I thought of those examples, but the skating moves are named _after_ the skaters. A Ford or a Škoda are also surnames. Neither are the same as this usage.

Comment: Not too important: Your examples actually refer to several different contributions to Mathematics and Physics by the great Henri, not only the famous conjecture now proven through the work of Grigori Perelman. For example, the "group of symmetries of flat spacetime" is an object from Lie theory known as the Poincaré group.

Comment: @KarlG but Fords and Škodas are physical objects, which fits Michael's theory of the difference.

Answer (score 38):

I think the point is not that Nasar and Gruber are native speakers of English.  Instead the point is that they are not mathematicians, and that mathematicians would usually not call the Poincaré conjecture merely "the Poincaré".

Now an art lover might indeed call the Guggenheim museum simply "the Guggenheim".  So this question is not about English language and usage so much as about customary ways of speaking.

Comment: Is understanding of the English language driven by theoretical (academic) precision, vernacular (customary) usage or both?

Comment: @GEdgar What is the difference between "usage" and "customary ways of speaking"?

Comment: As a mathematician (who also commented on the post in question), this is the correct answer to me.  As comments on Karl's answer establish, Poincare's name is attached to *a lot* of substantial or ubiquitous concepts in mathematics, as are many of the great mathematicians of old (and a few living ones).  There is no particular one to unambiguously refer to.  "The Guggenheim" is relatively clear, as there is really only one thing in the world that could be **the** Guggenheim (contrast with "a Guggenheim"). But there are many important things that could be "the" Poincare.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Indeed this is a better answer. I seem to remember a question in Math SE a while ago asking about all the different things named after Gauss. I can't find it right now, but imagine referring to "that Gauss thing".

Answer (score 18):

What does *the Poincaré* mean? It's a *conjecture*, so call it a conjecture. The comment is not about the use of *the* but about leaving out the head noun in a compound. You don't refers to *the toy store* as *the toy*, because it would make it completely unclear what you're talking about.

The lazy assumption that readers will assume that *the Poincaré* refers to a *conjecture*, instead of, say, a nice restaurant down the street, seems to have caused the dislike in the comment.

Comment: agree with your answer. another:  Magna Carta Libertatum (Medieval Latin for "the Great Charter of the Liberties") >  Magna Charta  > Magna Carta >  Great Charter

Comment: Oops. Looks like a naive misunderstanding by me. Thanks

Comment: I guess "there goes THE king" will never be "there goes da dude with the crown'?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting post!  Besides habits and customs within a certain social sphere, I think that there are at least two specific aspects that come into play here:

(1) Ambiguity vs. clarity:  Poincare, Einstein, etc., have made so many contributions that the meaning of "the Poincare" or "the Einstein" simply is not clear.  (This point has been made above already).

(2) Concrete thing or physical object vs. abstract idea or concept: Calling the paintings of Rembrandt, which are all unique and concrete physical objects, "Rembrandts", seems to work better than calling Mozart's music pieces (which are not tied to a certain physical representation or concrete object) "Mozarts".

In the case of "the Guggenheim" (museum), both conditions are fulfilled, and seem to foster the perhaps unusual use of the term as a metonym:  Firstly, the expression is unambiguous, since there is only one Guggenheim museum in town, i.e., per social sphere of the (imagined) speaker.  Secondly, "the Guggenheim" also refers to a unique physical object, namely the building itself.

On the other hand, calling the Guggenheim foundation, say, "the Guggenheim" does not seem to work as well, at least not as long as we try to refer to the abstract entity which the foundation constitutes.  It only seems more common when we refer to the physical building in which the foundation is located.  This presumably would also support our above observation (2) on physical objects vs. abstract concepts.