# 'The Kukhtarev's model' or 'Kukhtarev's model' ('John's car' or 'The John's car')?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, proper-nouns, objects

I think I know the answer to this but I just want to be sure. I have a supervisor who doesn't have a good level of English; sometimes he worries me with his corrections.

I was writing:

> Here, we will use Kukhtarev's model to describe the ...

But he corrected me:

> Here, we will use ***the*** Kukhtarev's model to describe the ...

I know this is wrong. However, can someone confirm this and explain why.

Comment: Possibly related: [english.stackexchange.com/q/438274](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/438274/289648)

Comment: I would accept *the Kukhtarev model*, personally, but making Kukhtarev possessive feels weird in "*the Kukhtarev's model*.  We don't say "the pythagoras' theorem", but we've nounified his possessive name to pythagorean, which makes "the pythagorean theorem" correct.

Answer (score 25):

**In short:**

The supervisor's edit is ungrammatical because it uses two Determiners within the same immediate noun phrase. As shown below, this is ungrammatical in modern English:

- *the my car

---

**The full story:**

> 1. the slimy dinosaurs

Noun phrases come in two chunks. They have a Determiner and a Head. In (1) above, the Determiner is the word *the*, and the Head is the phrase *slimy dinosaurs*.

The Determiner function is a grammatical relation. In other words, the term Determiner describes a job that a phrase or word carries out in a sentence. Examples of other functions are *Subject, Object, Predicative Complement* and so forth.

In the same way that Subjects are very often noun phrases, the Determiner function is very often carried out by a class of words called determinatives. These include words such as *a, the, some,this, that, no* and so forth:

> 2. a/the/some/any/no dinosaur

However, in the same way many other types of word, phrase and clause can function as Subjects, other types of word and phrase can be Determiners. Of particular concern to us here, genitive pronouns and other genitive noun phrases can appear in Determiner function:

> 3. [my] dinosaur - <sup>*genitive pronoun*</sup>
> 4. [that man's] dinosaur - <sup>*genitive noun phrase*</sup>

Now the pertinent rule relating to the original poster's question is that standard English will only allow one Determiner in any given noun phrase. Examples (5—8) below are therefore ungrammatical:

5. *the my dinosaur
6. *any her dinosaurs
7. *no those people
8. *a John's friend

---

**The Original Poster's Question**

The Original Poster's noun phrase was:

> (9) Kukhtarev's model

Here we see the genitive noun phrase (NP) *Kukhtarev's* in Determiner fnction within the larger NP. This is exactly analagous to:

> (10) John's car

Now it is possible that the supervisor was aiming to change this to:

> (11) the [Kukhtarev model]

Here, in (11), the word *the* is in Determiner function and *Kukhtarev* in contrast appears a modifier within the Head of the larger NP. The three possibilities here are that the supervisor did not notice the ***'s***,  that the supervisor made an incomplete edit and failed to delete the ***'s***, or that the supervisor's knowledge of English is incomplete. We cannot know. In any case the resulting string after the edit is categorically ungrammatical because it has two Determiners in the one NP:

12. *[the] [Kukhtarev's] model

Likewise so is the following:

13. *[the] [John's] car

If we wanted to use both a definite article and a genitive noun phrase we could use an oblique genitive construction to correct these:

14. the model of Kukhtarev's ...
15. the car of Johns' ...

Lastly, to avoid confusion, and before anyone asks, there is one situation where we might see the word *the* followed by a word like *Johns'* or *Smiths'*. This is where the Determiner is a plural genitive noun phrase:

16. [[the] Smiths'] car
17. [[the] Johns'] car

In (16—17), the word *the* is not a Determiner within the larger noun phrase. Rather it appears within the smaller Determiner noun phrase as shown. In (16) we might be talking about a car belonging to Mr & Mrs Smith and similarly for (17) a car belonging to Mr & Mrs John. We can't use a definite article when we refer to a singular person using a proper noun like this. The reason is that we don't use articles when using a singular referential proper noun:

18. *The John punched me  - *ungrammatical*

If the word *John* were not a name, but a common noun, for example the venacular for a toilet, or a prositute's client (as mentioned by @Weather Vane), then  there would be no problem with noun phrases like the following:

19. [[The] john's] door was wide open.
20. [[The] john's] car was parked outside.

In conclusion: the Original Poster needs to stick to their guns.

Comment: I'll not downvote this for lack of signs of research / attribution – there's obviously far more work been put into _this_ answer – but there's a lot of the CGEL flavour here.

Comment: Would the OP understand the idiom "stick to their guns"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good point. They seem quite proficient to me. But, if not, I think they'll get the gist either from the tldr or the body of the post. If not and they look it up, hopefully, they'll learn a colourful idiom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hopefully a lot of *both* the 2 CGEL flavours (with a bit of Aarts thrown in!)

Comment: Excellent answer! The only improvement I see would be "[[the] Smith's] car", showing that "[the]" is the determiner in the possessive noun phrase "[the Smiths']", which is itself a determiner.

Comment: @CJ Dennis Linked attributions would be an improvement.

Comment: @CJDennis Thanks! Wasn't sure if that would be too busy, but I agree it makes it much clearer

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is all common knowledge and quite uncontentious, unless you're a generative linguist. I teach it to language students (not in this way, of course) every day. I wouldn't know who to attribute it to! –

Comment: An attribution needn't be to the original source; a recognised authority will doubtless link to previous proponents.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much @Araucaria !  Spectacular answer

Comment: Just as on (say) SO, attributions are not relevant on "explain" questions on this site.  (If I explain how to do scrolling dynamic layouts or something on SO, there's no "attribution".)

Comment: I would accept *the Kukhtarev model*, personally. I don't know what that's called, when the name of someone's idea takes the form [inventor's name + generic noun], but seems common, and evolving from [possessive name form + noun] to ["the" + name + noun] seems only a matter of preference. Consider "the pythagorean theorem". An oddball would be Keynesian economics (said without "the"), since "economics" feels like a plural.

Comment: @fredsbend Yes, I think *the Kukhtarev model* (without the ‘s) would be just as acceptable, if not preferred. I think the difference with *Keynsian economics* is probably that *economics* is uncountable (perhaps compare with *Pythagorean trigonometry*).

Answer (score 19):

Short answer - you are right, your supervisor is wrong.

However he could have said

> "Here, we will use the Kukhtarev model to describe the ..."

The possessive is not used in this version.

So it's either "Kukhtarev's model" or "the Kukhtarev model"

Answer (score 3):

Peter Jennings answered part of the question. For the other part, if John is a person it should be

> We went in John's car.

But you didn't use a capital letter, and if **john** is slang for a **client** it should be

> We went in the john's car.

Of course, you would not use [**john**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/john) to mean a reputable business client.

Comment: @Araucaria I was about to post on meta about this.  But, I think it falls under the heading of this question I asked a few days back:  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13398/is-it-wrong-to-answer-a-question-that-youve-voted-to-close

Comment: @Araucaria you have edited the question **8 times** in all, rendering this answer irrelevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry if that's so. I specifically rolled it back so that discussion of John would be relevant. Please do edit as you see fit. Nearly all the edits were about the close/reopen or tags or formatting :( I'm happyvwith whatever you think is best.

Answer (score 2):

Kukhtarev's model ... yes
the Kukhtarev's model ... no
the Kukhtarev model ... yes

Comment: It may be correct, but it doesn't explain why it's correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Explaining why it's correct is the job of the Linguistics Stackexchange; papers can probably be written on it.